# Error while executing Appengine's downloadCloudSdk task in my subproject

Tags: google-app-engine, gradle, gcloud, app-engine-flexible

I am getting

```
com.google.cloud.tools.managedcloudsdk.ManagedSdkVerificationException: com.google.cloud.tools.managedcloudsdk.command.CommandExitException: Process failed with exit code: 1
```

I tried updating intellij and google cloud plugins. This task comes under

```
App Engine Flexible environment tasks > downloadCloudSdk - Download the Cloud SDK
```

for my project.

More logs with --info flag, I get

```
> Task :appengine-backend:downloadCloudSdk FAILED
Putting task artifact state for task ':appengine-backend:downloadCloudSdk' into context took 0.0 secs.
Up-to-date check for task ':appengine-backend:downloadCloudSdk' took 0.0 secs. It is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs.

:appengine-backend:downloadCloudSdk (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.349 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':appengine-backend:downloadCloudSdk'.
> com.google.cloud.tools.managedcloudsdk.ManagedSdkVerificationException: com.google.cloud.tools.managedcloudsdk.command.CommandExitException: Process failed with exit code: 1
```

Can anyone please suggest what might be wrong?

Comment: I fixed this myself by reinstalling google-cloud-sdk at another location and configuring gcloud again.

Comment: Could you put the resolution as an answer so that it can be useful to other people? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was happening because google cloud sdk was not installed properly. So, I removed cloud sdk and reinstalled it. After that, I realized that my gcloud config was not set properly, so I reconfigured that, i.e. made it what the project expected it to be. These steps resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

This answer worked for me at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-maven-plugin/issues/409#issuecomment-573389663

> I encountered this same issue. My environment:
>
> Mac OS
>
> JDK 8
>
> appengine-maven-plugin 2.2.0
> I was able to workaround it by removing this directory:
>
> ~/Library/Application Support/google-cloud-tools-java/

Then, the following will re-download the dependencies

`./gradlew appengineRun`

Answer (score 2):

This issue was happening for me as well I got got fixes for me by running this command `gcloud components update`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the gcloud App-Engine java component was missing, I had to install it by running:

```
gcloud components install app-engine-java
```

After that, the App-Engine maven plugin worked properly.